# Parallelization/Joblib ValueError: assignment destination is read-only

Tags: parallel-processing, joblib

I am attempting to parallize a function in python using Joblib (https://joblib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/generated/joblib.Parallel.html#joblib.Parallel). The functions inputs are three arrays and a list.

When using a small subset of the array (900 entries) there is no problem and the function works as anticipated. However, when using the entire array (50,000+ entries) I get a 'ValueError: assignment destination is read-only' error. My assumption is that the list I am generating from the values returned from the function is being set to read-only and therefore an error is being encountered. Perhaps this is due to the number of jobs being allocated? Or something to do with the way the result is being handled? I am not sure so I was looking for some input. The line for running the function in parallel is included below.

```
result = Parallel(n_jobs=-1, verbose=1000)(delayed(func)(array1, array2, array3, ls) for ls in list)
```

This works fine for small samples, it returns a list with the expected entries but fails for larger sets of data.

I have tried to decrease the number of jobs sent through the pre_dispatch argument but encountered the same issue. Are there any other arguments I could try or is it likely due to the result not being in shared memory?